# Saving array to local storage (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to save products from shopping cart to local storage, but on page refresh it does not work like it suppose to. When I refresh page, products are in shopping cart, but soon as I add new item, it gets erased. Also, deleting product deletes everything, not the specific one when using local storage. This is what I tried:

in `App.tsx` set array

```
const [productList, dispatch] = useReducer((state: any, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "ADD_ITEM":
        const noDoubleItems = state.filter((item: any) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
        localStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify([...noDoubleItems, action.payload]));
        return [...noDoubleItems, action.payload];

      case "DELETE_ITEM":
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state));
        return state.filter((item: any) => item.id !== action.payload.id);

      default:
        return state;
    }
  }, []);
```

in `Cart.tsx` get array

```
  const storageCart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
  const storageCartObject = storageCart && JSON.parse(storageCart);
```

Here is code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-torvalds-tevby?file=/src/components/pages/Cart.tsx:298-1026

Comment: Are you using Redux ?

Comment: Reducer functions (in redux or other plain react) [should really be _pure_ functions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-redux-needs-reducers-to-be-pure-functions-d438c58ae468/), meaning they return a new state and have no other side effects. Writing to local storage is a side effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your storageCart is initialized with the localStorage, but your Redux state is not initialized. So, the storageCart is still there, but when you dispatch the ADD_ITEM action, the Store is empty, that's why the first product you added disappears.

You can also use redux-persist to persist the Redux store every time the user refresh the page. So you don't need to handle all the local storage stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I had to install ```npm install use-persisted-reducer --save```, create persisted reducer like so ```const usePersistedReducer = createPersistedReducer('state')``` and replace ```useReduer``` with ```usePersistedReducer```, that simple!